# Java: Cannot Find Object while using Comparable Class

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have two programs. one called GeometricObject1 and another one called Circle1 which extends Geometric Object1. however when i use the compareTo method and another method that takes in 2 object from Comparable. the compiler gives the error message of `"Cannot find symbol"`.

Ive tried switching the names of the objects around, but i honestly have no clue what else to do. The method names are all from a skeleton that i was told to follow, im just stuck on the last two methods that are within Circle 1.

```
abstract class GeometricObject1 {

    protected String color;    
    protected double weight;

    // Default construct
    protected GeometricObject1() {
        color = "white";
        weight = 1.0;
    }

    // Construct a geometric object
    protected GeometricObject1(String color, double weight) {
        this.color = color;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    //Write code here for Abstract method for area
    public abstract double findArea();

    //Write code here Abstract method for perimeter
    public abstract double findPerimeter();

}
```

// Other Program

```
class Circle1 extends GeometricObject1 implements Comparable {

    protected double radius;

    // Default constructor
    public Circle1() {
        this(1.0, "white", 1.0);
    }

    // Construct circle with specified radius
    public Circle1(double radius) {
        super("white", 1.0);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    // Construct a circle with specified radius, weight, and color
    public Circle1(double radius, String color, double weight) {
        super(color, weight);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public static Circle1 max(Comparable o1, Comparable o) {
        if (((GeometricObject1) o).compareTo(o1) == 1) {
            System.out.println("The First Object is larger than the Second
                    Object");
        } else if (((GeometricObject1) o).compareTo(o1) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Both Object is equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The First Object is smaller than the Second");
        }
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    // Implement the findArea method defined in GeometricObject
    public double findArea() {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    // Implement the findPerimeter method defined in GeometricObject
    public double findPerimeter() {
        return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    public boolean equals(Circle1 circle) {
        return this.radius == circle.getRadius();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[Circle] radius = " + radius;
    }

    @Override
    // Implement the compareTo method defined in Comparable
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (findArea() == ((GeometricObject1) o1).findArea())
            return 0;
        else if (findArea() > ((GeometricObject1) o1).findArea())
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback. And welcome to upvote levels. One final hint: dont try to pull such things together all by yourself. There are many tutorials out that there give nice, small examples on how to use Comparable, Comparator and what not. Read those carefully, instead of trying to make sense ... just by writing your own code. Programming is not about putting down many lines that maybe do what you want. Programming is about understanding **each and any** character you write down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things wrong with your code. The error is simple:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (findArea() == ((GeometricObject1) o1).findArea())
```

The parameter is named **o**, but you want to use **o1**. Can't work. o isn't o1. Hint: use **real** names, that carry meaning and intent. Don't call it o, but `otherCircle`. Don't call it `o1` and `o` (as in your max method, but `firstCircle` and `secondCircle` for example). o and o1 are really easy to read/write wrong. Real names ... are really hard to use in the wrong way.

Then: you don't need to compare three times manually:

```
return Double.compare(findArea(), ( (GeometricObject1) o1).findArea());
```

would do what you need.

And: you are using a **raw** type.

```
class Circle1 extends GeometricObject1 implements Comparable {
```

should be

class Circle1 extends GeometricObject1 implements Comparable {

and when doing so, the correct signature of that method becomes:

```
public int compareTo(Circle1 otherCircle) {
```

( as you are **leaving** out the generic parameter, thus you have to deal with Object, and casting )

Also note: you are declaring an `equals()` method that does **not** override the base `equals()` method from class Object. That can lead to all kinds of problems (you need to make the parameter of type `Object`, and you should put @Override in front of *any* method you want to override).

Finally: your max method is also super confusing. Don't call `compare()` repeatedly, simply call it once, and remember the result of that call.

Comment: I switched the compareTo() method to take in o1 and that fixed the 2 errors from that method. however, it still cannot find symbols within the max method (im new to coding so thats why its confusing) and it says the location is in class GeometricObject1. is this because in the class definition i have not implemented Comparable?

Comment: As I told you: your code is full of problems. If you still have problems, update your question, but then: give the exact error message, too. Rather try to show us less code, as in [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You're likely getting a compile error here:

```
((GeometricObject1) o).compareTo(o1)
```

`GeometricObject` doesn't implement `Comparable`, so that method doesn't exist there.

Another case is in your `compareTo` method:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (findArea() == ((GeometricObject1) o1).findArea())
```

The object `o1` doesn't exist here, so the compiler doesn't know what you're referring to.

There are a number of other issues I'd suggest addressing with your code, but those are the specific errors you're asking about. Looks like GhostCat did a more thorough code review pointing out these issues already.

Answer (score 0):

This section still produces the error message:

```
  Circle1.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
  else if (((GeometricObject1)o).compareTo(o1)==0){                               

  symbol:   method compareTo(Comparable)
  location: class GeometricObject1
  2 errors




if (((GeometricObject1)o).compareTo(o1)==1){
System.out.println("The First Object is larger than the Second 
Object");
}
else if (((GeometricObject1)o).compareTo(o1)==0){
System.out.println("Both Object is equal");
}
else {
System.out.println("The First Object is smaller than the 
Second");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Im not familiar with the proper way to 'update' my problem.